# getJSON unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm trying to get earthquake data from USGS and I keep getting the error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**

I tried $.ajax with jsonp format and I keep getting the same issue. I tried without callback at the end of my url as well, in that case I get the error:

**MLHttpRequest cannot load http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojson. Origin http://people.oregonstate.edu is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

```
$.getJSON(
   "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojson&callback=?",
    function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
 );
```

can someone help me out how to get the data or perhaps something other than jQuery if it is not possible this way.

Comment: That service is not wrapping the calback function name around the data. Sure they have jsonp support?

Comment: This service is not providing JSONP, just regular JSON.  And since you are on a different domain, you cannot access this service directly through the client.  You need to set up a proxy on your own domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easiest way to get around it would be to tell the service you want jsonp, then use the callback provided by the service.

```
window.eqfeed_callback = function(data){
    console.log(data);
};
//$.getScript("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojsonp");
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojsonp";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: You Sir are awesome! I was about to implement a php proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Use their JSONP service at http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojsonp

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojsonp',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'eqfeed_callback'
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```